# Count events received on a Kafka topic during a fixed period of time

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, windowing

I have a 'users' Kafka topic, which receives messages with AVRO and contains a USERID. I wanted to have the number of messages per USERID received only on the last-minute window. So, following the diagram on the image below, I wanted the result to be:

| USERID | MESSAGE_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

[image]

I tried to:

1. Create a stream from that topic so that I can perform operations on it.

> CREATE STREAM users_stream
> WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='users', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

2. Create a table, which emits the information I want per minute on `my_table` topic.

> CREATE TABLE my_table AS SELECT  USERID, count(*) as message_count FROM users_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTE) GROUP BY USERID;

3. Create a pull query on the table, so that I can have the very last items emitted.

> SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;

However, the query emits lots of values, with repeated USERID. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in a different way, without using windowing. For testing my solution, I assumed a topic 'users' that receives messages on JSON format like the following:

`{"equipment": "fridge", "power": 10, "measured_time": "2022-02-22"}`

In order to get the number of messages per equipment sent with measured_time between '2022-01-31’ and '2022-02-28', I did the following:

1. Set configs

> SET 'ksql.query.pull.table.scan.enabled'='true';

(in order to make a pull query without WHERE clause, i. e., the last step)

> SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';

(in order to handle past events)

2. Create stream from users

> CREATE STREAM USERS_STREAM (equipment varchar, power double, measured_time varchar) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='users', VALUE_FORMAT='json');

3. Create a converted stream

> CREATE STREAM CONVERTED_STREAM AS SELECT equipment, CAST(measured_time AS DATE) AS MY_DATE
> FROM USERS_STREAM;

4. Create a table, in order to make aggregations

> CREATE TABLE USERS_TABLE AS SELECT equipment, COUNT(*)
> FROM CONVERTED_STREAM
> WHERE MY_DATE > '2022-01-31' AND MY_DATE < '2022-02-28'
> GROUP BY EQUIPMENT;

5. Make a pull query, so that future events are not considered

> SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE;

I hope it helps someone! If there is a better solution, please let me know!